# Find a three-digit number in a string using replaceAll()

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I have `String` from which I need to extract a keyword.

Something like: "I have 100 friends and 1 evil".

I need to extract "**100**" from that `String` using only `replaceAll` function and appropriate `regex`.

I tried to do it in that way:

```
String input = "I have 100 friends and 1 evil";
String result = input.replaceAll("[^\\d{3}]", "")
```

But it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the meaning of extract in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider any of the solutions below:

```java
String result = input.replaceFirst(".*?(\\d{3}).*", "$1");
String result = input.replaceFirst(".*?(?<!\\d)(\\d{3})(?!\\d).*", "$1");
String result = input.replaceFirst(".*?\\b(\\d{3})\\b.*", "$1");
String result = input.replaceFirst(".*?(?<!\\S)(\\d{3})(?!\\S).*", "$1");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AjEkPw/1). **NOTE** you may use `replaceAll` here, too, but it makes little sense as the replacement must occur only once in this case.

Here,

- `.*?` - matches any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(\d{3})` - captures into Group 1 any three digits
- `.*` - matches any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible.

The `(?<!\d)` / `(?!\d)` lookarounds are digit boundaries, there is no match if the sequence is four or more digits. `\b` are word boundaries, there will be no match of the three digits are glued to a letter, digit or underscore. `(?<!\S)` / `(?!\S)` lookarounds are whitespace boundaries, there must be a space or start of string before the match and either a space or end of string after.

The replacement is `$1`, the value of Group 1.

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/NlLg5w):

```java
String input = "I have 100 friends and 1 evil";
System.out.println(input.replaceFirst(".*?(\\d{3}).*", "$1"));
System.out.println(input.replaceFirst(".*?(?<!\\d)(\\d{3})(?!\\d).*", "$1"));
System.out.println(input.replaceFirst(".*?\\b(\\d{3})\\b.*", "$1"));
System.out.println(input.replaceFirst(".*?(?<!\\S)(\\d{3})(?!\\S).*", "$1"));
```

All output `100`.